# Can I use EF 6 in an ASP.NET Core solution?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am building MVC app in .NET Core but I was wondering If I can use EntityFramework 6.0 with it instead of EntityFramework Core?

I was just briefly testing and it looks like I can add EF 6.0 via Nuget package but would I meet any more conflicts if I proceed with it?

I am just very comfortable with EF 6.0 so I am asking this.

Comment: If the app will target .NET Framework, then you won't have a problem. If the app will target .NET Core, you won't be able to add the package

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thanks!

Comment: There isn't really that much difference between EF and EF core.  Once the context has been created it's virtually the same.  Sure there are a few things not available but not much these days (Ef 2.1 supports lazy loading for example).

Answer (score 2):

EntityFramework 6 requires the .NET Framework, not Core

But an ASP.NET Core web application can also be built on .NET Framework.

So create a ASP.NET Core Web App based on .NET Framework and that project, and any dependencies than use Framework will be able to use EF6.

(As noted in the comments to the question) there is a documentation page for this case: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-2.1